# How to push a variable to another component array in Vue.js

Tags: laravel, vuejs2

I created two components with Vue.js and Laravel (FormComponent and ListComponent). In the form I should enter a movie name and then when I click the input button I should see the new movie in the list of movies that is located in ListComponent... however I am unable to do that. I alert the new movie correctly but I cannot see the new movie in the list.

FormComponent:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="movie">Movie:</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" v-bind:placeholder="movie_default" v-model="movie_default" id="movie">
            </div>
            <input type="button" value="Submit" @click="add_movie()">
        </form>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Form Component mounted.')
        },
        data() {
            return {
                movie_default: 'Rainman'
            }
        },
        methods: {
            add_movie () {
                alert(this.movie_default);
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

ListComponent:

```
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <ol>
            <li v-for="movie in movie_list" :key="movie">
                {{ movie }}
            </li>
        </ol>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('List Component mounted.')
        },
        data() {
            return {
                movie_list: [ 'Titanic', 'Profondo rosso']
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Tables.blade.php

```
<div id="app">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <form-component></form-component>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
            <list-component></list-component>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have some different ways to solve your problem.
I would suggest you the easiest for the result I think you want to accomplish.

Create a third component my-form, that looks like this:

```
       myForm.vue
         <template>
           <div class="row">
             <div class="col-sm-6">
                <form-component @new-movie="addNewMovie"></form-component>
             </div>
             <div class="col-sm-6">
                <list-component :movies="movies_list"></list-component>
             </div>
            </div>
         </template>

    <script>
        export default {
        name: "myForm.vue",

        data() {

            return {

                movies_list: [],
                new_movie: ""
            }
        },
        methods: {
         addNewMovie(movie){
             this.movies_list.push(movie)
           }
       }
      }
    </script>
```

then edit your FormComponent to emit the new value on click:

```
methods: {
            add_movie () {
                alert(this.movie_default);
                this.$emit('new-movie',this.movie_default);
            }
```

and your ListComponent to use props instead of the state to display the movie list:

```
export default {
    props:['movies'],
    data() {
        return {
        }
    }
```

and update your v-for with to use the prop:

```
        <li v-for="movie in movies" :key="movie">
```

Another way would be to use a centralized store (vuex) to share the state between components

Comment: I tried in your way but I cannot see the movies in the list. If I click 3 times the button I see three numbers with empty values in the list.

Comment: No I solved... I forgot the {{ movie }} inside the li tag

Comment: what is the meaning of "<form-component @new-movie="addNewMovie"></form-component>"... I don't understand this sintax.

Comment: ciao Michele. So, @ is a shorthand for v-on: so basically is listening for an event. new-movie, is the event name that we defined in the form component (this.$emit('new-movie')). and addNewMovie is the name of the method to add a movie. You use it without `(args)` because the arguments get automatically injected in your function. Hope this helps!