# How to update the data from another component method

Tags: vue.js

I have a two Vue components

component A

```
<template>
   <div v-for="(item, index) in items" :key="index" class="row">
    <input v-model="item.body" class="form-control">
    <button v-on:click="updateItem(item)" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
    <button v-on:click="deleteItem(item.id, index)" class="btn btn-danger">X</button>
   </div>
    <input v-model="newItem" class="form-control" placeholder="Add new item...">
    <button v-on:click="addItem" class="btn btn-success">Add</button>
 </template>

 <script>
  const headers = {
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
 }

 export default {
  data: () => {
  return {
    newItem: '',
    items: []
  }
},
created: function() {
  fetch('/todos')
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => this.items = data)
},
.....
```

Component B

```
 <template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div>
        <div v-for="(user, index) in users" :key="index" class="col-md-2">
          <div v-on:click="nav_click_user(user)">
            {{user.username}}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>


<script>
  import Todo from './todos.vue'
  const headers = {
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  }

  export default {
    data: () => {
      return {
        users: []
      }
    },
    created: function() {
      fetch('/accounts')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((data) => this.users = data)
    },
    methods: {
      nav_click_user: function(user){
        fetch(`/todos?assignee=${user.id}`)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => Todo.items = data)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

I gets the result from the ajax response, But I'm facing difficulties in modifying the Items in the component A from the `nav_click_user` method in Component B

Comment: You can use `vuex` to achieve this scenario, Hope they are not in parent-child relation.

Comment: Can You explain a bit deeply ?

Answer (score 2):

## Case 1

If you are using two components under same parent like

```
<parent>
  <componentA/>
  <componentB/>
</parent>
```

You can pass the data to the children using `props` and get the changes back to the parent through `$emit` event.

```js
Vue.component('ComponentA', {
  props: ['text'],
  template: `<div>{{text}}
  <button @click="$emit('change', 'New Text Component B')">Change B</button></div>`
})

Vue.component('ComponentB', {
  props: ['text'],
  template: `<div>{{text}}
  <button @click="$emit('change', 'New Text Component A')">Change A</button></div>`
})
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: `<div>
  <ComponentA :text=textA @change="(e) => (textB = e)" />
  <ComponentB :text=textB @change="(e) => (textA = e)" />
  </div>`,
  data() {
    return {
      textA: 'ComponentA',
      textB: 'ComponentB'
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.x/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

## Case 2

If the components are parent-child relation like

```
<componentA>
   <componentB :data=data/>
</componentA>
```

In the above case, you can send the data from A to B using props and get back the same using `$emit` events.

## Case 3

If the two components are not at all related something like

```
<parent>
  <ComponentA/>
</parent>
<ComponentB/>
```

In the above case, you can use a `Vuex` Store. It will store the data and you edit it from componentB, which will be reflected to componentA.

For further details about the VueX, feel free to go through [docs](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/)

Comment: Mine is Case1, Can u elaborate a bit upon case1., I'm new Vue

Comment: Hi, maybe this answer of mine yesterday can help! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62792794/how-to-push-a-variable-to-another-component-array-in-vue-js/62793128#62793128

Comment: @Raffobaffo , Do we really need a third component for that??

Comment: Not really. To complicate things, you can use vuex, or to make things easier, you can put the component B inside component A and use the data() of component a as a prop to component B